# UIAppearance's setTitleTextAttributes causes UINavigationBar title set in storyboard to appear with ellipsized title in iOS 6 but not iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, ios6, uifont, uiappearance

i have been using what i had thought to be some fairly standard iOS 5 code (and which is a [7x accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440333/774691) on stackoverflow) in order to have my UINavigationBar's title appear with a customized font.]

but i have discovered that when my app built for iOS5 (so that it can run on both iOS5 and iOS6 devices) is run on the iOS6 simulator, it ellipsizes my title.

[image: iOS 4 inch Retina display simulator running iOS 6.0]

the following is the same code running on the iOS 5.1 simulator.

[image: iOS 3.5 inch Retinda display simulator running iOS 5.1]

for clarity, the following is the pertinent code that's been working until i tried running on iOS 6.

```
#define COURIER_FONT_BOLD @"CourierNewPS-BoldMT"

- (UIFont*)navigationBarTitleFontPortrait
{
    if (!_navigationBarTitleFontPortrait)
        _navigationBarTitleFontPortrait = [UIFont fontWithName:COURIER_FONT_BOLD size:24.0];
    return _navigationBarTitleFontPortrait;
}

// …

    if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)])
    {
        NSDictionary* attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                                                UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
                                                                UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                            navigationBarTitleFontPortrait,
                                                                UITextAttributeFont,
                                            nil];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attrs];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i discovered two solutions to the above problem:

1. set the title text to something of a different size in the
   .storyboard (in my case, i entered "...", and then in `viewDidLoad`,
   call `self.navigationItem.title = @"the GRID"`;
2. in viewDidLoad, perform `[self.navigationController.navigationBar
   setNeedsLayout]`.

i prefer the latter because it feels less like a kludge.  i am guessing the first solution forces the second to happen, anyway.

don't know why this behavior is different between iOS 5 and iOS 6, but this allows it to work in both.