# How to change these colors on Navbar?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have succesfully change the navbar button with this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:26.0/255 green:132.0/255 blue:182.0/255 alpha:.5]];
```

What about if I want to change the color of the title (from black) or the color of the button?

[image]

Comment: The button color can you change by setting the tint color of the navigationbar

Comment: And you can change the titleColor by setting the  titleTextAttributes property

Comment: You may take help from the following link-here


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430298/how-to-set-font-color-of-the-title-in-uinavigationbar-using-ios5-appearance-ap

Comment: @SilentStalker the answer in that link is now using deprecated code.

Comment: Why I cannot add image to my question like usual? I tried to add https://www.evernote.com/shard/s209/sh/c3720f97-38da-4d85-86e1-dd5b95a2d679/b4cbf9106654d1872834a19d7ccdbb68/res/83eb1c65-1530-4d7f-a490-f6dd0bc15479/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have in my App Delegate in a method specially for changing appearances.

```
// set button tint colour to white
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// set the bar tint colour to purplish
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.2 green:.458823529 blue:.592156863 alpha:1.0]];

// set title text label colour to white
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Answer (score 1):

For navigation bar title color in iOS7 you should use the setTitleTextAttributes of UINavigationBar appearance

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,shadow, NSShadowAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

For more navbar customization refer http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/