# iOS: How to set the navigation bar title text from bold to thin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

In my navigation bar title, the text always appears to be bold and I need to have a thin text. I don't want to use a label with attributed text. So is it possible to change the navigation bar title text from bold to thin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set font & color of the title in UINavigationBar using iOS5 appearance API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430298/how-to-set-font-color-of-the-title-in-uinavigationbar-using-ios5-appearance-ap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIAppearance

```
 NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{
    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:MY_FONT_HERE]
    };
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes];
```

Comment: @AnandK adjust font using appropriate size. If that doesn't work take the title on a diet.