# Get the Foreground Color for a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I can't read the foreground color defined into the `titleTextAttributes` property of a `UINavigationBar` instance.

Here is my attempt:

```
label.textColor = navigationBarInstance.titleTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] as! UIColor
```

The titleTextAttributes is defined as `var titleTextAttributes: [NSObject : AnyObject]?` so one of the error that I get is that I cannot subscript that properties using a `String` (`NSForegroundColorAttributesName`). The second error that I receive is that I cannot a sign a value of type `UIColor` to a value of type `UIColor!`.

I'm really confused! I just want to get the color of the navigationBar title and copy it into a `label.textColor` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430298/how-to-set-font-color-of-the-title-in-uinavigationbar-using-ios5-appearance-ap

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4.2

```
let navigationBarForegroundColor = navigationBar.titleTextAttributes![NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] as! UIColor
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as potentially low-quality. Please elaborate a little more on why this works so that future viewers and new developers understand why your answer is a valid solution.